# With the power to draw you in (and be swept away by the joy of puzzling)

Tags: word, pattern, crosswords

Instructions:

1. Solve the enigmatic crossword
2. Each answer clues a letter
3. Take only the 9 letters which were clued more than once (to find 9 distinct letters)
4. Apply the title and anagram the result for the final relevant answer (single word)

[image: crossword]

> **Across**
> 1 A cry such as "No!", "Oh!", or "Yikes!"
> 10    Vanquishes a queen a second time
> 12    Members of the genus Mustela, now and then considered vermin
> 13    Writing utensil  containing permanent or non-permanent ink
> 14    One who might find a lost pea under her mattress
> 15    Items which Jesus broke and gave away five of to a large crowd
> 17    Throwing away, such as with old lip gloss
> 22    Playful trick or caper, often without a logical reason
> 23    Number of letters in morse code ending with a dash (for example, 'A', not 'Z')
> 24    Sets with figurines, including camels, sheep, and a flying angel
> 26    Explicitly, as in: "Here are my friends, _____, A. Denver and Y. Lost."
> 27    Ground jay restricted to China
> 30 Parent who is not a mom
> 31    Clear and precise, for example: "third cleft from the right"
> 32    States of balance, all void of a net change
> 35    Having an unfavorable condition due to the lack of a feature required for success
> **Down**
> 1 Word teacher might write on an exam which scored ten out of ten
> 2 Gushing down rapidly, like nog from a pitcher
> 3 Having no sharp ends, like a bee missing its stinger
> 4 New York baseball team, not at Shea Stadium anymore
> 5 Law, for example that passed by the British Parliament in 1773, which resulted in Americans dumping tea into a harbor
> 6 One who trims shrubs into decorative shapes
> 7 Cloth made from flax, perhaps the material of a Noel table runner
> 8 Religious woman, often non-marrying
> 9 Diaphragms of human eyes, running in two layers
> 11    Celebration or gala - for example, a party at a floss factory
> 16    Official order or decree, perhaps given with a stern voice and a nod
> 18    Scientist who first discovered that water is produced when H is burned
> 19    One regarded as a standard of perfection - as opposed to one considered a fool or lout
> 20    Sign seen in planes; also a 2007 Indian film in which soldiers chase away K, a businessman
> 21    Having no known owner, like M & M's spilled on the floor of a mall
> 25    Head honcho; one who might say "When I give the order, clear out, 'kay?"
> 27    Transport tissue in a plant (helps explain why leaves, so high up, can get water)
> 28    Hospital word often filled with the no…is…e of crying infants
> 29    Speak on the fly (and often be without preparation)
> 31    Give food or drink, for example when presenting milk to a cute kitten
> 33    Destroy or purge, such as to mice, to ensure they are eradicated
> 34    Lump on a tree, such as a yew, hiding an undeveloped leaf

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Gimmick:

> Each clue has one or more words that clue a letter being removed in some way. There are generally two types of these indicators. The first comes in the form of [remove] [letter clue] (or vice versa), such as "why leaves" (why = Y because of homophones), vanquishes a queen" (queen = Q because of chess), or "ten out" (ten = X because of roman numerals). The other is a single word, which can be divided up into two words, such as "cleft" -> "C left" or "nog" -> "no G". This indicated letter must be removed from the answer to the clue before being entered into the grid.

Solved grid and clues:

> [image: Grid]
>  [image: Across Clues]
>  [image: Down Clues]

Extraction:

> We can now follow the given instructions. Every single letter in the alphabet is clued as being removed at least once, and 9 unique letters are clued more than once, namely [ABGIKLNTY]. Looking at the title, there is the subphrase "be swept away", which, interpreted in the same way as the crossword clues, suggests to remove the letter B. Therefore, the answer comes from anagramming the letters in [AGIKLNTY], which gives **TAKINGLY**, which is fitting to the theme of taking away letters.

Comment: I suspect your missing word (28D) is rot13(A(-v)PH)...

Comment: Looks right to me, editing now

Comment: Nice twist on crosswords